# Prove that $\int_1^b a^{\log_b x}\, dx>\ln b,$ where $a, b>0$ and $b\ne 1.$

Tags: integration, inequality

We have:

\begin{align}
I&=\int_1^b a^{\ln x×\log_b e}\, dx\\\\
&=\int_1^b \left(a^{\log_b e}\right)^{\ln x}\, dx. 
\end{align}

Let $a^{\log_b e}=k$ and $\ln x=t\implies x=e^t\implies dx=e^tdt.$ Also $x=1\implies t=0$ and $x=b\implies t=\ln b.$

Thus,

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\ln b} (ek)^t\, dt\\\\
&=\frac{(ek)^t}{\ln(ek)}\Bigg |_0^{\ln b}\\\\
&=\frac{(ek)^{\ln b}-1}{\ln(ek)}\\\\
&=\frac{b\cdot k^{\ln b}-1}{1+\ln k}\\\\
&=\frac{ab-1}{1+\log_b a}.
\end{align}

Since, $k^{\ln b}=a^{\log_b e×\log_e b}=a$ and $\ln k=\log_b e×\log_e a=\log_b a.$

Now my actual question is how to show that $\frac{ab-1}{1+\log_b a}>\ln b$ ? Or is there any other way to show that $I>\ln b$ without actually evaluating the value of $I$ ?

Please suggest... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $ek > 1$. Once you've gotten
$$I = \int_0^{\ln b} (ek)^t \,dt,$$
simply observe that $(ek)^t > 1$ for all $t > 0$, and so $I > \int_0^{\ln b} 1 \, dt$. If $ek \leq 1$, then the opposite inequality is true, and the statement is in fact false. Thus, the statement is true iff $ek > 1$ (it's sufficient to assume $a > 1$; did you mean to include this condition?)

Comment: @Dhrubajyoti Bhattacharjee Sorry, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Only $a>0$ was given..  But I understand if $ek\le 1$, then the statement doesn't hold.

Comment: yeah, that's correct. $ek \leq 1$ is equivalent to $a \leq e^{-\ln b}$, so the problem fails for all $a$ satisfying that inequality.